# Snapshot of UI while debugging in visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging a Windows form application in visual studio 2012. How can i see the snapshot of the UI while debugging?

Comment: The question is unclear: there are many screen capture tools available. What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Print screen is built in to windows. Sometimes labelled "PrtSc" on the keyboard. Use Alt-printscreen to snapshot just the window. There is also a "Snipping tool" program available in some versions of windows.

Comment: I think maybe the OP meant that while debugging the application won't respond to Paint events and so commonly the UI is lost: it doesn't repaint when obscuring windows are removed.

Comment: Good idea @StuartWhitehouse, however the question does not explain the problem clearly.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows Vista and Later, the Desktop theme may affect the appearance of the App UI when the code is frozen at a breakpoint within the debugger.  In Windows 7, for example: with Aero theme enabled, the current app UI is usually still visible if other obscuring windows are moved or closed, because Aero retains an image of the UI.  So, for example, minimizing Visual Studio will typically let you see the application again.

If Aero is disabled (eg switch to a Basic theme in Win 7), then the app UI will not respond to paint events, and if other windows on top of it are removed or moved, the result is gibberish.  If working on 1 monitor, once Visual Studio stops at a breakpoint you will no longer be able to see the UI until the code runs and responds to any pending Paint events.

So, if your question was about the UI freezing when the code is paused, enabling Aero might solve it.